# Regex to capture the useragent from the citrix logs

Tags: regex, citrix

Need help in capturing the user agent details from the citrix logs. The log format of the citrix is quite different for the successful and denied. The samples are given below

For Successful authentication the user agent details are enclosed within  "". Details are after the keyword Browser_type ""

For Denied traffic , useragent details are not present within the "". It is present after the keyword Browser

**Denied**

> Dec  8 05:20:53 netscaler02  12/08/2017:05:20:53  netscaler02 0-PPE-0 : AAA LOGIN_FAILED -adasd92 0 :  User renju - Client_ip X.X.X.X - Failure_reason "External authentication server denied access" - Browser Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36

**Success**

> Dec  8 05:54:06 netscaler02  12/08/2017:11:54:06 GMT netscaler02 0-PPE-0 : SSLVPN LOGIN -78342434122 0 : Context renjus@1X.X.X.X - SessionId: xxx- User renju - Client_ip X.X.X.X - Nat_ip "Mapped Ip" - Vserver X.X.X.X:443 - Browser_type "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36" - SSLVPN_asdasdat_type ICA - Group(s) "N/A"

I do have a regex to capture the browser agent within ""

> (?P(?<=Browser_type\s\").*?(?=\s*(?:\w+=|\")))"

Bud need a regex that capture the user agent from all the format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could match your logs like this:

[`Browser(?:_type)?\s"?(.+|[^"]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/IxHyHX/1)

- Match Browser with optional _type `Browser(?:_type)`
- Followed by an optional double quote `"?`
- Followed by a whitespace `\s`
- Then capture in a group `(` any character zero or more times `.*`
- or `|`
- all until you encounter a double quote `[^"]+`
- Close the group `)`

**Edit:**

To capture "Browser" without the optional "_type" in a named capture group:

[`(?P<citrix_useragent>Browser)(?:_type)?\s"?(.+|[^"]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/EZea1u/1)

Comment: Hi  Thanks for the help. your query logic is right but need a little tweaking. Please do help me out  tried this one out  but capturing the keyword browser in front of the user agent details(?P<citrix_useragent>(?:Browser(?:_type)?\s"*(.+"-|[^"]+))). Any workaround

Comment: @List25 If you want to capture "Browser" without the optional "_type" in a named capture group, you could do it like this [`(?P<citrix_useragent>Browser)(?:_type)?\s"?(.+|[^"]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/EZea1u/1)

Comment: @ The fourth bird  : Thanks for the reply . Did some intial workaround and found out the regex what im looking for                             
            Browser((?:_type)?\s\"*)(?P<UA>(.+\"-|[^\"]+))

Answer (score 0):

Got the initial push from **The fourth bird** and did some work around on it.

> [Browser((?:_type)?\s\"*)(?P(.+\"-|[^\"]+))](https://regex101.com/r/GCFBzT/1)